# Get each span height and if it's more than 40px change the css

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me, I don't understand where the error is.

This is my jQuery:

```
function altezzadotgrey(){
    $('.views-field-title').each(function(){
        var aaltezzadotgrey = $(this).outerHeight();
        if ($(this).outerHeight() > 40) {
            $(this).css("margin-top", "-45px");
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content"><a href="">a</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content"><a href="">b</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content"><a href="">c</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row">
    <div class="views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content"><a href="">d</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think there could be a problem with the `each()`.

Comment: does your span has `height` in your css ?

Comment: Why does this not achieve what you need?

Comment: no, there's no height on my span this is my css
margin-top: -25px;
padding-left: 3px;
background: url("/sites/all/themes/acquia_prosper/images/dot_grey_trasp.png") transparent;
position: relative;
width: 172px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
color: white;

Comment: ok, but do you use your function `altezzadotgrey()` somewhere?

Comment: that's the only part where i use that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.css uses "DOM style" properties rather than the CSS style, so you this:

```
$(this).css("marginTop", -45);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4upSX/1/

Actually it works with "margin-top" also... so are you sure your '.views-field-title' are actually higher than 40px?

Answer (score 0):

```
function altezzadotgrey(){

  $('.field-content').each(function(){

        var h= $(this).css('height');
        if (parseInt(h)  > 40) {
            $(this).css("margin-top","-45px"); 
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: `span` is an inline element.Does it has `outerHeight` ?..correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your function on body load

```
$( function() {    
    altezzadotgrey();    
});

function altezzadotgrey(){
    $('.views-field-title').each(function(){
        var aaltezzadotgrey = $(this).outerHeight();
        if ($(this).outerHeight() > 40) {
            $(this).css("margin-top", "-45px");
        }
    });
}
```

Everything else is correct